# Grails criteria vs list

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Why does this works:

```
def index() {

   params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)

   respond Myclass.list(params), model:[myclassInstanceCount: Myclass.count()]
}
```

But this does not:

```
def index(){

   params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)

   def criteria = Myclass.createCriteria();
   def myclassInstanceList = criteria.list(){
      property("name");
   }

   respond myClassInstanceList, model:[myclassInstanceCount: Myclass.count()]
}
```

Edit 1:
Myclass.list(params) gives me a list of Myclass objects.
myclassInstanceList...(from criteria) also gives me a list but of java.lang.Object objects.

Comment: What doesn't work? Your question isn't very clear. What is happening? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: I expected the list to show  me an index, but it shows blank. (No items on index, just the layout as if the myclassInstanceList were empty)

Comment: It's a good question. I have no idea why you are being downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong, are you not getting any errors in backend ? property("name"); should be inside projections {} block. and even after that it will return list of just names not whole MyClass